# Is Count Rugen a nod to going up to eleven?

Tags: reference, the-princess-bride, this-is-spinal-tap

In *This is Spinal Tap* Christopher Guest’s character Nigel Tufnel has amplifiers with knobs that can be [set to eleven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_to_eleven). In *The Princess Bride* Guest plays Count Tyrone Rugen who, with a sixth finger on his right hand, has a total of eleven fingers. Has Rob Reiner or anyone else in the cast or crew mentioned Rugen’s eleven fingers as a deliberate reference to *This is Spinal Tap*?

Comment: Count Rugen has 11 fingers in the book The Princess Bride, which came out in 1973. Since This is Spinal Tap wasn't released until 1984, they are likely unrelated. (Unless this is stunt casting, but that seems unlikely.)

Comment: @Kitkat ... why don't you turn that into an answer.